# Move one of two element in absolute position based on one

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project which is available here:

```css
.carousel-promo {
    font:normal 14px sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
}

.carousel-promo button{
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color:  #87bae1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
 z-index:20;
 position:relative;
}

.carousel-promo .product-out-of-stock{
    color: #c15017;;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
 z-index:20;
 position:relative;
}

.carousel-promo .product-price{
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color:  #4e4e4e;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 6px;
 z-index:20;
 position:relative;
}

.carousel-promo .sale_badge{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 top:-3px;
 left:-3px;
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 transition: all 150ms ease-in-out 0s;
 border-radius:50%;
 line-height:60px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 font-size:14px;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#83d4fb;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
}

.carousel-promo .image{
 position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-promo">
   
<div class="item">
    <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150"  alt="" /></div>
    <button>Buy Now!</button>
             <p class="product-price">$599.00</p>
   </div>
      </div>
```

What am trying to do is to get some thing like this:
[image: What I want to get]

But I am facing two problems:
1- I am unable to place the price tag just like on the above image
2- Using the css property `top: 170px;` on the button `Buy Now` and the price will help me to place them under the image. Is there any possibility to place the button `Buy Now` and the price at the desire place without using the css property `top: 170px;` ?

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.carousel-promo {
    font:normal 14px sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
    position:relative;/* ADD THIS property */
}

/* ADD THIS CLASS */
.carousel-promo.item{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-promo button{
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color:  #87bae1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
    z-index:20;
    /*position:relative;*/ /*remove this property*/
}

.carousel-promo .product-out-of-stock{
    color: #c15017;;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
 z-index:20;
 position:relative;
}

.carousel-promo .product-price{
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color:  #4e4e4e;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 6px;
 z-index:20;
 /*position:relative;*/ /*remove this property*/
}

.carousel-promo .sale_badge{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 top:-30px; /*Up to 30*/
 left:-30px; /*Up to 30*/
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 transition: all 150ms ease-in-out 0s;
 border-radius:50%;
 line-height:60px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 font-size:14px;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#83d4fb;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
}

.carousel-promo .image{
 /*position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;*/ /*REMOVE absolute*/
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-promo">
   
<div class="item">
    <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150"  alt="" /></div>

    <button>Buy Now!</button>
             <p class="product-price">$599.00</p>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your help.